# BookshelfJs failing to bring in nested relationship on create

Tags: postgresql, express, join, bookshelf.js, knex.js

Let's say we have a Join table `vehicle_inspections` and another join table `inspection_actions`, as well as basic tables for `actions`, `vehicles, and`inspections`.

Lets say I desire the following DB entries:

```
 vehicles
 ----------------------------
 id        make
 ----------------------------
 1         Toyota



actions
-------------------------------
id        description
-------------------------------
2         Check Tire Pressue

inspections
-------------------------------
id        location        date
-------------------------------
3         New York      tomorrow

vehicle_inspections
--------------------------------
vehicle_id      inspection_id   
--------------------------------
1                3

inspection_actions
--------------------------------
inspection_id     action_id
--------------------------------
3                 2
```

and the following bookshelf classes

inspection_actions.js

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
     var Repository = require('../repository');
     module.exports = Repository.Model.extend({
       tableName: 'inspection_actions',
     });  
})();
```

vehicle_inspections.js

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
     var Repository = require('../repository');

     module.exports = Repository.Model.extend({
       tableName = 'vehicle_inspections',
       inspection: function () {
         return this.belongsTo(require('inspection'));
       },
       fetchOrCreate: function(vehicleId, inspectionId, options) {
         var self = this;
         return self.query(function (qb) {
           qb.where({
             vehicle_id: vehicleId,
             inspection_id: inspectionId
           });
         )}.fetch(options || {}).then(function (model) {
           if (!model) {
             model.save({
               vehicle_id: vehicleId,
               inspection_id: inspectionId
             });
           return model;
         };
       }
     };
});
```

inspection.js

```
...
module.exports = Repository.Model.extend(_.extend({
   tableName: 'inspections',
   actions: function () {
     return this.hasMany(require('./inspection-action'));
   }
}));
```

And a route:

```
 new VehicleInspection().fetchOrCreate(req.params.vehicle_id, req.params.inspection_id, {withRelated: ['inspection.actions']})
 .then(function (vehicleInspection) {
    var inspection = vehicleInspection.related('inspection');
    console.log( inspection);
    console.log(inspection.related(actions);
  })
```

The inspection console log prints out the correct inspection, however, irrelevantly of what is in the database the second console.log prints out an empty result

```
 { length: 0,
  models: [],
 _byId: {},
   ...
  targetIdAttribute: 'id',
 foreignKey: undefined,
 parentId: undefined,
 parentTableName: 'tasks',
 parentIdAttribute: 'id',
 parentFk: undefined } }
```

This "bad" behaviour only occurs the first time a projectTasks entry is being created. What appears to be happening is that the inspection_action table is not being populated through the nested `withRelated`. How could I get this working nested create working?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not completely clear what you are trying to achieve, but here is how I would generally set things up. First I'd create a base model (assuming its saved as base.js), I think you are going to have some problems with circular dependencies, so using the Bookshelf registry plugin would be good:

```
var config = {
  client: // whatever client you are using,
  connection: // url to your database
};
var db = require('knex')(config);
var Bookshelf = require('bookshelf')(db);
var Base = Bookshelf.Model.extend({
   // Put anything here that will be helpful for your use case
});
Bookshelf.plugin('registry');

Base.model = Bookshelf.model.bind(Bookshelf);
module.exports = Base;
```

Next create your Vehicle model:

```
 require('inspection');
 require('action');
 var Base = require('base');

 var Vehicle = Base.Model.extend({
   tableName = 'vehicles',
   inspections: function () {
     return this.belongsToMany('Inspection',
       'inspections_vehicles', 'vehicle_id', 'inspection_id');
   },
   actions: function() {
     return this.belongsToMany('Action',
       'actions_vehicles', 'vehicle_id', 'action_id');

   }
 };
 module.exports = Base.model('Vehicle', Vehicle);
```

Then an inspection model:

```
 require('vehicle');
 var Base = require('base');

 var Inspection = Base.Model.extend({
   tableName = 'inspection',
   vehicles: function () {
     return this.belongsToMany('Vehicle',
       'inspections_vehicles', 'inspection_id', 'vehicle_id');
     }
 };
 module.exports = Base.model('Inspection', Inspection);
```

Finally an action model:

```
 var Base = require('base');

 var Action = Base.Model.extend({
   tableName = 'actions',
 };
 module.exports = Base.model('Action', Action);
```

Now assuming that the database isn't already filled in with the data you supplied, we can populate it:

```
var Inspection = require('inspection');
var Vehicle = require('vehicle');
var Action = require('action');
var toyota;
var newYorkInspection

Vehicle.forge().save({name: 'Toyota'})
  .then(function(vehicle) {
    toyota = vehicle;   
    return Inspection.forge().save({location: 'New York', date: 'Tomorrow'});      
  }).then(function(inspection){
    newYorkInspection = inspection;
    return toyota.inspections().attach(newYorkInspection);
  }).then(function() {
    return Action.forge().save({description: 'Check Tire Pressure'});
  }).then(function(tirePressureAction) {
    return toyota.actions().attach(tirePressureAction);
  });
```

Now I can fetch the toyota vehicle with the related actions and inspections:

```
var Vehicle = require('vehicle');
return Vehicle.forge({'name': 'Toyota'}).fetch({
  withRelated: ['inspections', 'actions']
}).then(function(toyota){
  var toyotaInspections = toyota.related('inspections');
  var toyotaActions = toyota.related('actions');
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your informative answer (I've upvoted).

After some more digging, I've narrowed down the problem to being on creation and modified my question appropriately to expose the fetchOrCreate fully, and to elaborate.
The short version is: the .fetch works as is, how ever the .save does not create the nested relationship 'inspection.actions', not populating the inspection_actions table with the right entry and thus returning the empty array correctly. I'd love to hear any thoughts you have on fixing that problem :)

Comment: First, try vehicleInspection.related('actions') to get the actions. Second, when you call fetchOrCreate, if the fetch fails because the object doesn't exist yet, and you create it, the returned model will be just the inspection_action model, with no relations. If you wanted the relations you would have to do another fetch after the save.

Comment: Love this organization, but am having issues with getting it set up correctly.  I'm getting `Object function () { [native code] } has no method 'extend'`. Any chance you can point me in the right direction? https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a66d38ad8f62ba22f122

Comment: Ugh. As so often happens, I think I figured out (a|the) solution minutes after asking for help. Looks like `var Listing = App.extend({ ... });` works rather than `App.Model.extend({ ... });`. Nonetheless, you have my up-vote for the great structure.